# Rails: Keep controller after AJAX call

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a question about the data in the controller after an AJAX call from the view.

I have a dropdown which uses remote: true to be able to work with AJAX

```
<%= t('label') %> <%= collection_select("items", :id , @items, :id, :selector_title, { :prompt => false, :selected => @selected_id }, {:data => {:remote => true, :url => "/controller/do_something", :method => "post"}}) %>
```

In the routes file I specified the route

```
 match '/path_to_controller_method',      to: 'controller#do_something', via: 'post'
```

This works all fine. The do_something method gets executed in the controller. 
What I do not understand is, why are the variables like:

```
@wrapper
```

`nil` which I initialized in the index method? Do I have to reinitialize all variables again, after an AJAX call from the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An AJAX call is an independent call that has an assigned controller, and an assigned method within that controller. It works pretty much like a normal request, except that it doesn't reload the whole page.

Now, the variable: `@wrapper` - if it has been initialized in `index` method, now it needs be initialized in the assigned method: `do_something` too, or you could do something like `before_action`, initialize the method there, and call `before_action` before `index` & `do_something`.

All in all, an AJAX call works like pretty much any other request, and you need to initialise all the instance variables unless you are using `before_action`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I got it.

Comment: @AlexBug If my answer helped you, you can accept it.